# Filter mongo collection if item exists inside array using Golang and bson

Tags: go, mongodb-query, bson

I want to find all users inside my collection who have a friend( ***primitive.ObjectId*** ) inside of an array that the users object has.

```
filter := bson.M{ "friends": bson.M{"$in": id } }
cursor, err := GetDB().Collection(UserCollection).Find(ctx, filter)
```

I get the following error:

```
err (BadValue) $in needs an array
```

any suggestions

Comment: If the `friends` field is an array, you can simply do `bson.M{"friends":id}`

Comment: So I do not need the &in ? Let me try that. Thank you